# Can someone provide a php sample using nusoap/sugarcrm api to create an acct/lead in sugarcrn?

Tags: sugarcrm, nusoap

Can someone provide a sample code chunk of php using the sugarcrm API/nusoap for adding creating an acct. and then linking a lead to the acct?

I've got a sample function that adds a lead, and I can see how to create an acct, but I can't see how to tie a lead to the acct, to simulate the subpanel process in the sugarcrm acct/subpanel process.

thanks

```
// Create a new Lead, return the SOAP result
function createLead($data)
{
    // Parse the data and store it into a name/value list
    // which will then pe passed on to Sugar via SOAP
    $name_value_list = array();
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
        array_push($name_value_list, array('name' => $key, 'value' => $value));

    // Fire the set_entry call to the Leads module
    $result = $this->soap->call('set_entry', array(
        'session' => $this->session,
        'module_name' => 'Leads',
        'name_value_list' => $name_value_list
    ));

    return $result;
}


$result = $sugar->createLead(array(
    'lead_source' => 'Web Site',
    'lead_source_description' => 'Inquiry form on the website',
    'lead_status' => 'New',
    'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
    'email1' => $_POST['email'],
    'description' => $_POST['message']
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the ID for the account and assign that ID to whatever the account_id field name is in the Lead Module. I have run into a couple things like this before and I have found it easier to go straight to the Sugar database. So, write a statement that will return the account is, for example: SELECT id WHERE something_in_the_account_table = something else;

Then you can assign that id in your $result array. I hope it helps. I didn't have any code or documentation in front of me or I would have helped more.